# Round Up Date - Require Complete Year

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a sheet to calculate employees length of service.

[image]

Now with my current formula

> =DATEDIF(D2,E2,"y") & " years, " & DATEDIF(D2,E2,"ym") & " months, " & DATEDIF(D2,E2,"md") & " days"

I am getting 11 years, 7 months, 9 days

But I need this "**12 years**" instead of "11 years, 7 months, 9 days". Also if it is less than 6 month[example: 11 years, 5 months, 9 days] in result should come previews year[**11 years**].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Excel on this machine, but something like this should work:

```
=ROUND(DATEDIF(D2,E2,"d")/365.25, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's returned to "You've entered too few arguments for this function"

Comment: Try adding `,0` before the final parenthesis. As I said, I don't have Excel on this machine; I expected that you could do the fine-tuning on your own.